# Television series about a space station

Tags: story-identification, tv, space

I remember watching this TV show in the 90's set aboard a space station. It featured an eccentric cast of characters including a security guard reminiscent of Bruce Willis, an alien with abnormal hair, and an alien with an abnormal head. The special effects looked like they came from a video game of the time. Can anyone help me identify this show?

Comment: As Mike mentioned, this was Babylon 5.  It is one of greatest pieces of science fiction every created for television and far too many people missed out on it because it ran in syndication at often odd hours of the day or night.

Comment: I literally expected the punchline question about time traveling robots in this one.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed - it's just like any other "identify X for me" question. Granted the details are a bit sparse - but easily answered.

Comment: @HorusKol Check out the original version of the question and the close reason

Comment: Why do people go to all the trouble of reopening and editing this question, when it was clear from the start that the OP has no intention of contributing anything meaningful to this site. My advice is to roll back the edit and close and/or delete it for good.

Comment: @MrLister: Maybe SE is more than a means to ask a question. It's also a means to discover that your question has already been asked and answered. Thus, a good question has worth that exceeds the needs of the original asker.

Comment: There's no way I could have answered this....

Answer (score 19):

That's certainly [Babylon 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5). Although I always thought that Jerry Doyle looked more like Bruce Willis than Bruce Willis himself did.

Comment: Jerry Doyle is the ultimate Bruce Willis, and far better than Bruce himself.

Comment: There's an episode of Moonlighting where they break the 4th wall and Jerry Doyle is among a group of actors auditioning for Bruce Willis' part in Moonlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't have been 'Space Precinct', maybe?

Comment: Could you be more descriptive - what was the show about, how well does it match with what's in the question, etc?  As it is, just throwing a name out there barely answers the question...

Comment: Well, there have been plenty of people suggesting Babylon 5 and the OP hasn't risen to saying any of them are correct, so it figures OP is either A; Lazy, B; hasn't been back or C; it's not Babylon 5.

The only other show I can think of from that time period, roughly that description is 'Space Precinct', of which a quick IMDB will give the OP the option of checking.

I didn't want to extrapolate an unnecessarily long winded explanation to an OP that might not even be interested anymore, when a quick sentence gives them the option to look for themselves.

Sometimes brevity is preferable.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to work for it. You were compelled enought to answer, but not committed enough to do so completely?

Comment: @wbogacz: exactly that, yes. I could have possibly included an IMDB link, but other than that there is little to add that wouldn't just be inflation. I had a kernel of an idea, and disclosed it.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional If you click on the OP's profile, you can see that they never came back.  While it certainly helps to provide suggestions, for story-ID questions, some sort of description of *why* an answer is a possible match is generally expected.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, I do not remember "Space Precent," was it anything like the British TV show "Star Cop?"  I enjoyed "Star Cop" because it was mostly near Earth orbit stuff.  If I remember they set up on the moon because the main character has a problem atapting to zero G.